# Duplicate method call VS local variable

Tags: java, performance, variables, methods

It it a problem to call the same method multiple times instead of creating local variable. I mean in term of performance.

```
int myLocalVarieble = bar.getLocalVariable();
foo1.setAttribute(myLocalVariable);
foo2.setAttribute(myLocalVariable);
```

Or

```
foo1.setAttribute(bar.getLocalVariable());
foo2.setAttribute(bar.getLocalVariable());
```

Comment: If `getLocalVariable()` itself has a significant performance overhead, or if it might change its value between calls, you might want to avoid calling it twice. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You'd better use JMH http://java-performance.info/jmh/ and create benchmark method to test your particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how expensive it is to call getLocalVariable(). For this particular example this seems relatively inexpensive because it's a simple getter, so no harm.

However, imagine that the getLocalVariable() takes 30 seconds to return, then the first example would be much more preferred.